# powershell special character user input validation

Tags: validation, powershell, input

I am wanting to validate a user's input of special characters and if the characters are not correct, I want it to loop back to the read-host statement. I am unsure what loop type I should use and how to do this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

For example

```
$Example = Read-Host “Input one of the following symbols 
Addition (+)
Subtraction (-)
Multiplication (*)
Division (/)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should suit your needs.

```
do {
    $Symbol = Read-Host 'Symbol'
    if ($Symbol -match '^(\+|-|\*|/)$'){
        $Valid = $true
    } else {
        Write-Host "'$($Symbol)' is not a valid input, please choose one of +,-,* or /"
        $Valid = $false
    }
} while (!$Valid)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.